# Fedora 21 wired internet problem

Tags: networking, fedora

Booted up Fedora on my desktop (previously was running w8.1, with also some network problems on restart/wake but usually a reset of the adapter solved them.)

No internet on the Fedora. Here are the outputs of  `ping 192.168.1.1` (i.e. the router), `ifconfig`, `ping www.google.com`, ping a google IP and `netstat`

[image: a]

Notice the extremely high packet loss on the pings. What could be wrong, what to try?

Comment: probably a loose/bad ethernet cable. Have you tried using another one?

Comment: Are you confident that there are no duplicate IP addresses on your local network?

Comment: @PandaLion98 Can it still be a bad cable if it sometimes works perfectly, sometimes this error occurs? But I guess I'll give it a shot with a new cable.

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, no duplicate ip's. I'm using DHCP and checked for the router's page that all the clients have different ip's.

Comment: Does `arping` show similar symptoms?

Comment: @Shepherd Yes. Yes it can. Have you tried a fake charger cable where certain positions make it work while some doesn't?